# How to assign a the result of `Command::arg()` to a field?

Tags: rust, mutable-reference

tokio's [arg()](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) returns a mutable reference to a [Command](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/process/struct.Command.html). How can I assign it to a field?

```
pub struct Manager<'a> {
    pub cmd: &'a mut tokio::process::Command
}

impl<'a> Manager<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Manager<'a> {
        Manager {
            cmd: tokio::process::Command::new("ls").arg("la")
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

Comment: In the future, please always post the full error from `cargo check`, not part of it or errors from IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method returns a reference to the same `Command` it was invoked on, just to make it easy to chain method calls (`command.arg("abc").arg("def").spawn()`). You may as well ignore its return value and just assign the `Command` to the field:

```rust
pub struct Manager {
    pub cmd: tokio::process::Command,
}

impl Manager {
    pub fn new() -> Manager {
        let mut cmd = tokio::process::Command::new("ls");
        cmd.arg("la");
        Manager { cmd }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This approach is actually way better